# What's the proper size of a custom AppBarButton image

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

In stead of using the default symbol icons from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx), I want to create some custom icons. Then I read upon [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662743.aspx) which explains how to achieve this.

```
<AppBarButton Label="BitmapIcon" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/globe.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

The above is working great. But my question is: what should the size of the icon image be (in this case globe.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question you can find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx):

> Icon images should be 48 x 48 pixels in size. The foreground graphic for the button should fit in a 26 x 26 area in the center of the image so that it does not overlap the circle.

Microsoft also [published *PSD* files for assets](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266547) - the link stands for Windows Phone 8 assets, but as far as I know the appbarbutton's icon hasn't changed.